# is there a tool to extract files from git commits

Tags: git

At work we use git for version control, but not for pushing to development and test sites (attempts have been made to set this up, but no success).

Instead we have to put together patches by copying the files in the correct paths to an update folder in the form of `\sitename\developer-date-001\` which is then applied manually via ftp by someone else.

Is any tool that could look at a git repository and duplicate just the files changed between certain commits into the correct directory structure to make creating those patches more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

[`git format-patch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html) and related commands will probably do what you're looking for. [`git diff`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) will also create patch-formatted diffs.

Comment: I think the question is not about creating diffs, but copying just the changed files.

Comment: If he clarifies the question, I can probably clarify the answer.